# Hydrostatic Equilibrium in Galaxy Clusters

Tags: galaxy-clusters

One of the methods of mass calculation in Galaxy Clusters is to make a profile of the X-Ray gas and then (after several assumptions) assume hydrostatic equilibrium: the force pushing down on the gas (gravity) is equal to the amount of force pushing up (pressure of the plasma).  What is unclear is: how do we know the gas inside the cluster isn't spinning?  It seems to be that any angular momentum, however small, would invalidate the assumptions of equilibrium.

Comment: A uniformly spinning mass of gas can also reach an equilibrium (with the given angular momentum).

Comment: @SebastianRiese Wasn't the question asking about how angular momentum makes the push down not equal to the pressure out (since they sum to a centripetal acceleration instead)?

Comment: @Timaeus I guess, your interpretation of the question makes more sense.

Comment: @SebastianRiese - Yes, like Timaeus said, the centripetal force would invalidate the assumptions of balance (at least, it seems that way to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct that X-ray estimates of gas mass usually make the assumption of hydrostatic equilibrium and ignore rotation. Both of these assumptions are open to challenge. Clusters are thought to have formed through a rich history of mergers that could leave them out of equilibrium or impart some angular momentum. These issues are of course being thoroughly explored, are generally well known in the literature, and are comparatively small effects compared with the "dark matter" problem (see for example [Suto et al. 2013](http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.5172)).

For the angular velocity to make a significant difference to the mass calculations then any centrifugal acceleration would need to be comparable with the gravitational acceleration.

Let's take the Coma cluster and assume a total mass of $10^{15}M_{\odot}$ within about 5 Mpc radius. Equating
$$\omega^2 R = GM/R^2,$$
we find rotation is important if $\omega \sim 6\times 10^{-18}$ rad/s. Sounds not much, but this means a rotation velocity of about 1000 km/s.

Detecting such gas motions in X-ray data with relatively modest spectral resolution is difficult. One can try to look for systematic doppler shifts in ionised iron lines. As far as I can tell, a 1000 km/s rotation is just on the edge of detectablity and *has* been observed in the Centaurus cluster by [Dupke & Bregman (2006)](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0512045). A source of additional support besides pressure, as could be contributed by rotation or turbulent motions would mean that the X-ray profile fitting would *underestimate* the total cluster mass (see for example [Suto et al. 2013](http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.5172)) . [Zhang et al. (2010)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0780) compare total cluster masses found from weak lensing and from X-ray measurements. The agreement was within 10% ! However, there is a hint of additional non-thermal support for some of the clusters.

Instead of directly looking at the gas we could look to the galaxies in  clusters for evidence of rotation. The velocity *dispersion* of the galaxies in the Coma cluster is also of order 1000 km/s (not a coincidence), but individual galaxy velocities can be measured to a precision that is a small fraction of this - easily sufficient to detect rotations of even 100 km/s, yet no definitive evidence for rotation in Coma has been found. In fact another way of thinking about this, is that the rotation will become important in the virial theorem if the systematic rotation accounts for a lot of the observed velocity dispersion.

[Hwang & Lee (2007)](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0702184) have done a systematic search for rotation using SDSS data. They find that about 20% of Galaxy clusters have significant rotation (rotational velocities becoming comparable to the velocity dispersion). In their table 6, the re-derive the total masses of these clusters, finding that they decrease by around 20% on average. So again, the effect is small (compared with the "dark matter deficit"), but worth considering.

Edit: A new study by Smith et al. (2015) appeared today ( http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.01919 ) that compares weak lensing masses with derivations based on X-rays and hydrostatic equilibrium. The headline ratio is 0.95 +/- 0.04 indicating that departures from hydrostatic equilibrium are generally small, at least in the local universe (z<0.3). However they do point out that the ratio falls to 0.6 for higher redshift clusters, but suggest that the data quality or other measurement biases are most likely responsible.

EDIT2: Another recent paper. [Maughan et al. (2015)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.07872) compare X-ray-derived masses (assuming hydrostatic equilibrium) with masses derived using the "caustic technique" (this is essentially using the kinematics of the visible galaxies to determine a mass profile). They conclude that  "*There is no indication of any dependence of the mass ratio on the X-ray morphology of the clusters, indicating that the hydrostatic masses are not strongly systematically affected by the dynamical state of the clusters. Overall, our results favour a small value of the so-called hydrostatic bias due to non-thermal pressure sources.*" The paper also has a good introduction that refers to a few other recent papers in the literature.

Comment: "The agreement was within 10%" - I can't remember where I read it, but wasn't there a problem with the weak lensing contours in that they were far to concentrated in the center to match up with a NFW Dark Matter halo?  That is, the total numbers were in good agreement, but the contours were way off.

Comment: "Instead of directly looking at the gas we could look to the galaxies in clusters for evidence of rotation."  Is there any rule that says the galaxies must follow the gas?  We're talking about densities that are still close to a vacuum (~$10^{-27} cm^{-3}$).

Comment: @DonaldRoyAirey The galaxies formed from/in the gas. Why would they rotate differently? Or to put it another way, what torques do you think act on the gas? Again - the comparison between virial masses from the galaxies and total lensing mass is excellent.

Comment: I'm not (even close to) an expert on hierarchical evolution, that's why I'm asking the question.  I guess the one idea I had is that a couple of core galaxies form the gravitational well, the gas is drawn into the well, additional proto-galaxies are drawn in, repeat until the present time.  The gas would have the average angular velocity where the galaxies with have a random trajectory.

Comment: @DonaldRoyAirey If so, there would be a clear discrepancy between total masses derived from the gas profile, gravitational lensing or the galaxy velocity dispersions.  This is part of my answer.

Comment: Molnar et al (2013) http://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.4691.pdf have found significant differences between the gravitational lensing and the mass derived hydrostatic equilibrium assumptions in A1689.

Comment: @DonaldRoyAirey The result is from Peng et al. (2009), Molnar did some modelling. Zhang et al. (2010) studied a large sample, finding $M_{lens}/M_{x}$ varied from about 0.5-1.5. Not sure what your point is.

Comment: @RobJeffereis What makes you think this is a contest?  I'm exchanging information.  That's my point.

Comment: I just got through reading Zhang.  I'm not sure I understand from where your earlier statistic of 10% comes.  The $M_{x}/M_{wl}$ ratio of 0.55 to 1.72 is, to my eye, a lot.  If a hydrostatic equilibrium calculates a mass of $1 \times 10^{15}$, then a weak lens can calculate a mass of $5.5 \times 10^{14}$ to $1.72 \times 10^{15}$?  What am I missing?

Comment: @RobJefferies I read through Molnar et al (2010) again and you seem to dismiss it for reasons I don't understand.  He performs modeling and then tests his model on A1689.  How is this process any less valid than the method of Zhang when it comes to establishing whether Hydrostatic Equilibrium is a valid assumption for Galaxy Clusters?

Comment: @DonaldRoyAirey There is a *scatter* and an uncertainty (mainly I think) in the X-ray masses. The average ratio is almost 1, indicating no huge systematic effects. Individual clusters can be discrepant, or is this just underestimated uncertainties? Hydrostatic inequilibrium should only push it one way, but there are discrepancies either way. I don't dismiss Peng's result. But it is one result.

Comment: I want to make sure I'm interpreting these results correctly.  When you say 'almost 1', we're talking about a disagreement between $M_{x}$ and $M_{wl}$ between 55% and 172%.  And there's the assumption of dark matter, so we're talking about 55% to 172% of roughly $1 \times 10^{15} M_{⊙}$?  Is that right?

Comment: You asked why would gas rotate differently than the galaxies.  Here's a quote from the Hwang and Lee document: "According to oﬀ-axis merging models, the global rotation of “collisional” ICM originated by merging survives longer than that of “collisionless” galaxies in clusters (Roettiger & Flores 2000). Therefore, it is expected that it is more diﬃcult to detect the global rotation of galaxies than that of ICM".  FWIW.